# Classpath is set, but still getting NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, maven, jar, classpath

I'm trying to package a very simple app into a jar to distribute to a user. I'm using Eclipse Indigo with the m2e plugin on Mac OS X 10.6.8.

I used the Maven build: package goal to package it as a jar. If I double click on the jar to open it, the GUI opens and appears to be working, but when I click the execute button, nothing happens. (The program works fine if I do Run As... within Eclipse).

If I try to run the jar from the command line, it won't even open the GUI, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: str-profile-comparison-0/0/1-SNAPSHOT    /jar
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: str-profile-comparison-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
```

I extracted the manifest file from the jar, to check the classpath, and it looks like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Built-By: username
Build-Jdk: 1.6.0_24
Class-Path: poi-3.7.jar poi-ooxml-3.7.jar poi-examples-3.7.jar xmlbean
s-2.3.0.jar stax-api-1.0.1.jar dom4j-1.6.1.jar xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar po
i-ooxml-schemas-3.7.jar geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec-1.0.jar poi-scratc
hpad-3.7.jar junit-4.8.2.jar
Created-By: Apache Maven
Main-Class: com.{companyname}.strprofilecomparison.logic.StrComparatorGUI
key: value
url:
mode: development
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
```

I have several questions about what is happening here:

1. Why does the GUI open when I double-click the jar file, but not when I try to run it at the command line?
2. I'm guessing the classpath needs to define the absolute path to the external jars I'm using, how do I set that in the POM file?

Comment: For 1, I don't remember if double click uses javaw instead of java.exe. Also, if you have more than one jre in your system, the double click may be loading one version and the command line another one. You need to check that.

Comment: I've just realized that it is the mac osx version. Still, different paths may apply when launching from double click, command line, or spotlight.

Comment: For 2, you may try maven assembly, which includes all dependencies in one big jar file. http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/

Comment: Classpath entries in the manifest are relative, not absolute. The class that it says isn't being found is actually a JAR file. Have you used a JAR filename as a classname somewhere?

Comment: Great, thanks for all the great answers. One more question, if I use the maven-assembly-plugin, do I use that in place of the maven-jar-plugin? Meaning I don't need the maven-jar-plugin anymore?

Comment: --EDIT: I answered my own question, the answer is Yes, maven-assembly replaces maven-jar plugin (for the benefit of future readers).

Answer (score 1):

That manifest says that all your dependencies are sitting in the same dir as your jar. If that's not true, no go.

Personally, I'd use the appassembler plugin to make a device that has a shell script to launch it. Or the shade plugin to make an uberjar that just incorporates them. Or learn about OSX stubs to make an OSX proper .app application.