# Jar works on double-click, but not in command line

Tags: java, maven, executable-jar

Following up on one of my questions in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10808209/classpath-is-set-but-still-getting-noclassdeffounderror).

I added the `maven-assembly-plugin` to my `POM`, and now the jar works, but only if I double-click on the jar in the file system. If I try to run the jar from the command line, I still receive this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
```

This concerns me, because it seems like this jar is not platform-independent. How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you provide the content of the the file META-INF/MANIFEST.MF from inside your jar

Comment: as jar is getting launched on double click, manifest should be there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

syntax to launch application from jar on cmd line

```
  java -jar jarname
```

Given that you have Manifest.txt file with jar having Main-Class:*package.class_name_containing_main_method*

Comment: <sheepish grin> I was missing the -jar switch. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

How do you launch it?

You need to use the `-jar` switch:

```
java -jar your_jarfile.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

That should not happen as launching it through command line is the exact same as launching by double click. Maybe you are trying to get it to use a different version of java through command line and that is what isn't working? to clarify, the command to launch a jar is `java -jar name.jar`